# Extracting an int among a line of text and splitting

Tags: c#

I am attempting to split a line from a text file into 4 strings and 1 int. I do not know how to extract the int part.

Can someone help me out here?

```
StreamReader infil = new StreamReader("moviefile.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
for (;;)
{
    string line = infil.ReadLine();
    if (line == null) break;

    string[] parts = line.Split('\t');

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.title = parts[0];
    movie.genre = parts[1];
    movie.release = parts[2];
    movie.actor = parts[3];
    movie.director = parts[4];

    AddMovie(movie);
}
```

Comment: What's the format of the file? What's the int we need?

Comment: Are you concerned about converting the string into an int?  If so, check out `int.Parse`

Comment: Can you Accept an Answer? I'm not saying it should be mine, but just for completeness... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 'release' is the year the movie was released, as an integer:

```
int release;
bool didParse;
while (true)
{
    string line = infil.ReadLine();
    if (line == null) break;

    string[] parts = line.Split('\t');

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.title = parts[0];
    movie.genre = parts[1];
    didParse = Int.TryParse(parts[2], out release);
    movie.release = (didParse) ? release: -1;
    movie.actor = parts[3];
    movie.director = parts[4];

    AddMovie(movie);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `(didParse) ? release : -1`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which member of Movie was an int.

It's fairly straightforward. For example, if genre was your int:

```
 movie.genre = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
```

Comment: It was movie.release.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll find slightly confusing is that in C#, there is `Convert.ToInt32`, `Int32.Parse`, and `Int32.TryParse` (and thats just for `Int32`... there are more variations for all the other ints and types)

```
StreamReader infil = new StreamReader("moviefile.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
for (;;)
{
    [...]
    movie.release = Int32.Parse(parts[2]);  // Parse parts[2] into an 32-bit (4-byte) integer.
    [...]    
    AddMovie(movie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the string is "SomeTitle SomeGenre SomeRelease SomeActor SomeDirectore 2008" using your code:

```
string[] parts = line.Split('\t');

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.title = parts[0];
movie.genre = parts[1];
movie.release = parts[2];
movie.actor = parts[3];
movie.director = parts[4];
movie.year = int.Parse(parts[5]);
```

That should work just fine.

Comment: No it shouldn't. There isn't a method called `int.tryparse`, and anyways the real version (`int.TryParse`) returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse a string to int

Assuming 'release' was supposed to be parsed into integer,

```
movie.release = int.parse(parts[2]);
```